# "Подьячий" в значении "подмастерье"

Tags: значение

Можно ли употреблять слово "подьячий" в значении "подмастерье"? Подьячий художника, мастера, скульптора.

Comment: Кто-то употребил, или это фантазия?

Comment: Скорее, фантазия. Однажды, видимо, в сознании соединились эти слова, объединенные приставкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Подьячий = под + дьяк//ч + ий - помощник дьяка, делопроизводитель, но никак не подмастерье.

По Ефремовой:

> Подьячий - 1. **Писец и делопроизводитель** в приказной канцелярии;
>   **помощник дьяка** (на Руси конца XV в. - начала XVIII в.). 
>   2. устар. **Мелкий канцелярский чиновник**.http://tolkslovar.ru/p11683.html

Современный толковый словарь изд. «Большая Советская Энциклопедия»:

> В Древней Руси тот, кто состоял на службе у князя, ведал его
>   перепиской и следил за доходами, назывался писцом. С XIV века, судя по
>   сохранившимся документам, на смену ему пришел дьяк. Это слово,
>   заимствованное из греческого языка, имело
>   несколько значений. Что говорят словари? «Диаконос» переводится на
>   русский язык как «служитель» и может относиться **к чиновнику или
>   низшему церковному сану.** В первом случае словари дают следующее
>   определение: дьяк – это должностное лицо в Московском государстве,
>   письмоводитель и начальник канцелярии разных ведомств. К таким
>   учреждениям относились, например, приказы – центральные органы
>   управления, возникшие на рубеже XV-XVI веков. Поэтому дьяки
>   представляли собой государственных служащих, получавших за свою работу
>   жалование. Их роль в жизни Московского царства особенно возросла в
>   годы правления Ивана Грозного. - Читайте подробнее на SYL.ru:
>   https://www.syl.ru/article/303822/dyak-eto-eto-chinovnik-ili-tserkovnoslujitel

Это ещё и низший церковный сан. Помимо приказных и думных письмоводителей, существовали также патриаршие певчие дьяки – профессиональные **церковные певцы**. Их не следует путать с прислужниками, которые помогали священнику во время отправления культа. Стоя на самой низкой ступени церковной иерархии, диаконы занимались организационными и административными вопросами, следили за состоянием здания церкви, руководили прихожанами во время богослужения, выполняли обязанности казначея и т. д.